# how to change username ,password in mysql database software

Tags: mysql

could you please help me, mysql datase username is root and there is no password for database.
now i want to give a password for mysql database.
please

Thank you
Tatarao voleti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('password you want')
```